# Count mountain arrays

Tags: java, algorithm

A mountain array has below features:

- all items in array are different
- size of array is A which is odd
- the items from 1 to A/2 are increasing
- the remaining items to right are decreasing
- the item at position (A/2 +1) is maximum

For given size of array A, and range of numbers from [1, B] inclusive, count how many mountain arrays are possible.

Count all possible distinct mountain arrays for given A and B.

**For example:**

```
A = 3, B = 4
```

**possible arrays are: 8**

```
1 3 2
2 3 1
1 4 3
3 4 1
2 4 3
3 4 2
1 4 2
2 4 1

We have 8 possible mountain arrays.

so result is 8.
```

My idea is to generate all possible arrays of size A using digits 1 to B, and finding if it is mountain array or not. But my approach takes lot of time. What is the correct approach to solve this problem.

This is my code to generate all possible permutaions:

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

```
public class Main {

    public static void kSubsetPermutations(String partial, List<Integer> set, int k) {
        for (int element : set) {
            if (k == 1) {
                System.out.println(partial + element);
            } else {
                List<Integer> copyOfSet = new ArrayList<>(set);
                copyOfSet.remove(Integer.valueOf(element));
                kSubsetPermutations(partial + element, copyOfSet, k - 1);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void solve(int A, int B) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=1; i<=B; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        kSubsetPermutations("", list, A);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        solve(3,4);
    }
}
```

Result can be large so use mod 10^9 while getting the count. So brute force approach is not the right way to solve this.

Comment: Does this problem have a web page? It could be a programming challenge / practice site, for example. If it does, it would be polite to include a link to the web page.  It could be me, but I don't understand what the 2nd paragraph is attempting to describe.  Can you, please, edit to clarify?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, don't have a page for this. ` It could be me, but I don't understand what the 2nd paragraph is attempting to describe` which point is that?

Comment: @OldDogProgrammer, Also I added example with values, clearly stating how a mountain array looks like

Comment: Unless specification of your homework says otherwise, your suggestion of brute force solution is a correct solution. You can then improve on it and prune some of the " "branches" of your array generator - eg. pick a top number which will be in the middle (some numbers won't be there ever) and that also narrows which numbers can be on left and right.

Comment: It was the paragraph telling us what a mountain array is. But, the edit does clarify. Thank you.

Comment: So for each k between A and B (start by picking the max element) you want to find out how many ways you can color numbers 1..k-1 with A/2 of one color (left) and A/2 of another color (right). Once you have the colors, left goes up, right goes down, translates to one specific arrangement. Sum over k.

Comment: How many ways you can pick x out of y elements is just binomial coefficients. If the range between A and B is large and you can't actually do the sum, some math may be involved to see if the sum can be simplified further.

Comment: faulty specification: if "the items from 1 to A/2 are increasing" and "remaining items to right are decreasing", then "item at position (A/2 +1) is maximum" cannot be true since A/2+1 is to the right of A/2 and so less than A/2 (since on the *decreasing side*)

Comment: @Igand generating all possible arrays is a terrible solution since the vast, vast majority of them will not be mountain arrays as defined. There are surely far better approaches.

Comment: @David Conrad oh I didn't realize not only this is homework, but it also one in mathematics rather then programming :) I imagined I should count those by constructing them in which case you won't asymptotically do better then brute force anyway. My bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of combinations of `B` things (the integers `1,2,...,B`) taken `A` at a time is given by the [binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient), whose equation is given by

<sub>B</sub>C<sub>A</sub> = B!/(A!*(B-A)!)

For each of these combinations of size `A` (an odd integer) one element is the largest. The number of ways `(A-1)/2` of the remaining `A-1` elements can be selected to precede the largest element is given by

<sub>A-1</sub>C<sub>(A-1)/2</sub>

For each of these combinations of `(A-1)/2` elements that are to precede the largest value the remaining `(A-1)/2` (unselected) elements are to follow the largest element.

For the `(A-1)/2` elements that precede the largest value there is but one ordering (smallest to largest) that satisfies the definition of a "mountain array". The same is of course true for the `(A-1)/2` elements that follow the largest element, except that ordering is largest to smallest.

The total number of mountain arrays that can be formed is therefore equal to

<sub>B</sub>C<sub>A</sub> * <sub>A-1</sub>C<sub>(A-1)/2</sub>

---

Suppose A = 3 and B = 4. The number of mountain arrays is seen to equal

<sub>B</sub>C<sub>A</sub> * <sub>A-1</sub>C<sub>(A-1)/2</sub> = 4!/(3!*1!) * (A-1)!/((A-1/2)!^2)
= 4 * 2!/1
= 8

Comment: My answer appears to be the same as @JohnBayko's, but I will leave it up because my presentation is somewhat different.

Comment: `For the (A-1)/2 elements that precede the largest value there is but one ordering (smallest to largest) that satisfy the definition of a "mountain array". The same is of course true for the (A-1)/2 elements that follow the largest element.` can you please explain more on this point, im finding it difficult to understand.

Comment: @technotigr first we select A out of B, the highest of that goes in the middle, then we select (A-1)/2 out of the remaining A-1 to go on the left and the rest goes on the right. One such selection identifies exactly one mountain array, because we have to arrange the left part in ascending order and the right part in descending order.

Comment: @technotigr To be clear it doesn't matter which elements you select for the left side. If you select the lower elements and sort them, there is a big gap between the highest on the left side and the maximum, but it still meets the definition. The remaining elements are sorted descending on the right side.

Comment: @JohnBayko, a small point. It may depend on the language being used but with Ruby, and I expect other languages, the combination method always return elements in order, so the elements on the left will be in order and those on the right will simply need be reversed; i.e., no sorting is necessary. If, for example, the array were `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9]`, one of the 126 5-element combinations would be `[2, 3, 4, 7, 9]`. After removing `9` and generating combinations of size 2 from what is left, one such combination (to precede `9`) is `[2, 4]` leaving `[3, 7]` for the right.

Answer (score 3):

For simplicity I'll use A as the size of the array. Given A and B, for the definition to work B >= A or A will have repeating elements.

First question is how many arrays can be selected from B values. The first element can be any B, the second can select from (B-1), and so on. (Note that choosing 1 then 2 is the same a choosing 2 then 1 - there are A! ways that can happen, so divide by that to get the number of *unique* selections), so the number of arrays is:

```
     B * (B-1) * (B-2) * ... * (B-(A-1))
(1) -------------------------------------
                      A!
```

which can also be written as:

```
           B!
(1') -------------
      A! * (B-A)!
```

That formula is known as "B choose A", and if you haven't taken a math or stats class that covers it, I don't expect you to follow how to get that from the sum up there.

Next question is, how many ways can the array elements be arranged in a "mountain". One is taken as the peak, so there are A-1 elements left. You need to select (A-1)/2 elements for the left side. They can be sorted after selecting, the important thin is how many you select, and no duplicates, so that's the same as above, with (A-1)/2 and (A-1) instead of A and B (the remaining elements make up the right side, they don't need to be selected explicitly, so that can be ignored).

Given that, the solution is:

```
                  (A-1)!
(2) -----------------------------------
     ((A-1)/2)! * ((A-1) - ((A-1)/2))!
```

So the total number of "mountain" arrays that can be created from choosing elements from 1 to B is (1) times (2). Simplify and compute and that should give you the answer.

Comment: The sum you have for point (1) is not the correct formula. The left side is not equal to the right side of the equation.

Comment: @trincot Sorry, I'm a little rusty. I think the gist is correct though. I'll review and see if I can correct it.

Comment: OP is computing mod 1e9, so division is not really available. Maybe using Pascal's triangle?

Comment: @teapot418 Yeah, I can see that. I'm out of time, maybe you can write that up.